# Resolve vSphere Client “Install VMware Tools” error message

Tags: vmware

I have installed VMWare ESXi server and connected to it via vSphere Client 5.5.0-1993072.

When I open the client, I get an error message on the summary tab saying “Install VMware Tools. See the vSphere Client Help.”

What is this message about and how can I solve it?

[image: the message]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the message in its context.

Comment: Edited my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not an error message.** It concerns the virtual machine you have currently selected. VMware Tools provide proper integration of a virtual machine into ESXi’s management tools, among other things. For example, it provides the VM host with the ability to gracefully shut down the guest operating system.

Therefor, VMware Tools should be installed right after installing the guest operating system in a VM.

VMware provides a [KB document on how to install VMware Tools with vSphere client](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004754):

> 1. Select the menu command to mount the VMware Tools virtual disc on the guest operating system.
>
>    - **vSphere Client** – Inventory > Virtual Machine > Guest > Install/Upgrade VMware Tools
>    - vSphere Web Client – All Actions icon > Configuration > Install/Upgrade VMware Tools
> 2. (If you are using vCenter Server and are performing an upgrade or reinstallation, in the Install/Upgrade VMware Tools dialog, select Interactive Tools Installation or Interactive Tools Upgrade and click OK.)
>
>    The process starts by mounting the VMware Tools virtual disc on the guest operating system.
> 3. If you are installing VMware Tools for the first time, click OK in the Install VMware Tools information screen.
>
>    If autorun is enabled for the CD-ROM drive in the guest operating system, the VMware Tools installation wizard appears.
> 4. If autorun is not enabled, to manually launch the wizard, click Start > Run, type D:\setup.exe, where D: is your first virtual CD-ROM drive, and click OK.
> 5. Follow the on-screen instructions. To install nondefault components, select the Custom setup.
> 6. If the New Hardware wizard appears, go through the wizard and accept the defaults.
> 7. When prompted, reboot the virtual machine.